# Return to Previous WatchKit Interface Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I have an interface controller that goes to another interface controller when a button is pressed. I do it like this

```
- (IBAction)setLocationPressed {
    [self pushControllerWithName:@"setLocation" context:self.appContext];
}
```

How can I return to the first controller when a button on the second one is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the documentation for `WKinterfaceController` (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/popController) you'll see two methods that are relevant to what you want to do: `popController` and `popToRootController`.